# How do you deal with outside data in a React event listener?

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, use-effect

In an event handler in React, how do you get and set outside data?

Here's an example that counts keyup events. Because the function is only created once, the listener always sees the keyup count as what it was initially, and it will never count above `1`.

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kfas0b7u/3/), or see code sample below.

```
function CountKeypresses() {
  const [keypressCount, setKeypressCount] = React.useState(0);

  const handleKeyup = (event) => {
      setKeypressCount(keypressCount + 1); //keypressCount is always 0 here no matter what
  }


  //Only create the event listener once
  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyup);
  }, []);
  
  return keypressCount;
}

ReactDOM.render(<CountKeypresses />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

Comment: Just in case you have not left it out to minimize the snippet size, you probably also want to clean up the event listener by using the return of the useEffect.

Answer (score 2):

Use the callback form of the setter so that you can set the new value to the *current* previous value plus 1:

```
setKeypressCount(keypressCount => keypressCount + 1);
```

Another option is to add and remove the listener every time `keypressCount` changes, though it's a bit uglier:

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyup);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyup);
  }, [keypressCount]);
```

If you're in a similar situation where you don't want to set state, but you need to get the current value in state, and the `useEffect` approach above isn't suitable, you can also store the value in a ref instead, but such situations are somewhat unusual in my experience.